# Javascript prototype best practices

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm trying to execute a method from the SubClass to the MainClass.
It works in this code, but is there a best way to do that (not to use the  "_parent" in parameter) ?
Thanks a lot for your help!

==> https://jsfiddle.net/jdrwwmt5/

```
var APP;
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        APP = function (id) {
            this.name = "MainClass"
            this.id = id;
            this.init();
        };
        APP.prototype = {
            init: function () {
                this.subClass = new APP.Sub(this);
            },
            onSubClassReady: function (_origin) {
                console.log(this);
                console.log(this.name);
                console.log(_origin);
                console.log(_origin.name);
            },
        };
    }());
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var Sub = APP.Sub = function (_parent) {
            this.name = "SubClass"
            this.parent = _parent;
            this.isReady = false;
            this.initialize();
        };
        Sub.prototype = {
            initialize: function () {
               //...
               this.ready();
            },
            ready:function (){
                  this.isReady = true;
                  this.parent.onSubClassReady(this);
            },
        }
    }());
    var app1 = new APP('1');
```

Comment: `Sub.prototype = {}` - this overwrites `prototype object`, it's bad. Better to add methods to it: `sub.prototype.metohdName = function () {};`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've updated the code thanks to you, but is there any other/best way to skip the "parent" parameter ??
=> https://jsfiddle.net/0cc7pmyx/

Comment: I've found this solution, is there a best way to do that ?
https://jsfiddle.net/4vfsa9eL/